# Is there a simple way to have a cell reference that is included in a formula increment vertically while copying formula horizontally?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, reference, array-formulas, cell-array

I want to be able to copy my formula from cell B4 into cells C4,D4,etc. so that the cell reference to B18 changes to B19, B20, etc. and the table column continues to reference [date].

I've tried referencing the cells in different ways, but I am having no such luck. When I try to drag the formula horizontally from cell B4 to cell C4 the reference to cell $B18 doesn't change but the table column that's being referenced changes from [date] to [platform].

The formula is `=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1,MATCH($B18,Table1[date],0),2),"")`

Does anyone know how I can adjust my formula to do this, or is there a different way to write it all together to make this easier?

[image: Screenshot of excel sheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can lock cell references with a double bracket for table columns `[[field]:[field]]`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1,MATCH($B18,Table1[[date]:[date]],0),2),"")
```

Comment: just realized that only solves half your problem. When you drag right, the value will stay at `B18`. You will need a counter of some sorts. You could also build a variable month (you have year in top right, month top left, and day above reference cell.) You can combine all of that to just simplify this down to a VLOOKUP to match on date

Comment: I ended up getting it to work with a VLOOKUP. Much easier, thank you for your help!